# Android-studio Android emulator Error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

When I run emulator under Android studio I have error in logcat view can you explain where is a problem in this log :

```
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d2f528 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-21 02:25:02.655    6902-6902/com.android.exchange           E/StrictMode: null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d2f528 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

it appears like an error in communication between avd and adb , how you can discover a mistake , with console commands

Thanks